# PDF fillable form shows garbage characters but disappear while click it

Tags: pdfbox

Please help me to explain this issue. I was using pdfbox-0.7.3, jdk-1.4.2 to fill PDF form, well, everything is good but some special character.

Please forgive me that I can't link pdf here, or I'll be fired:(
Any advice of this issue will be appreciated.

**For example:**
value is 6” w x 10 ¼” h.
**result as below images**

not clicked in:

[image: not click in]

clicked in

[image: click in]

Comment: Neal, you mention that you use pdfbox-0.7.3. That version is ancient and hardly anyone will fix anything there. Please try with 2.0.x or at least 1.8.x and report if the problem persists.

Comment: @mkl, I can't use new version, because our app was too old, big and EJB2 based. Maybe I should close this question. And thank you very much, I've seen you other replies, helped me to fix the font too large issue:) you're awesome.